# iterate through array, adjust a virtual attribute and return array with adjusted value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails class called a tag:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :is_enabled_on_item # a virtual attribute for ouptutting json
```

and I want to adjust the is_enabled_on_item like the following:

```
t.each { |tmp| tmp.is_enabled_on_item=true if current_tag_ids.include?(tmp.tagid) }
```

to get like:

```
[
   {
      tagid:1,
      phrase: "blue",
      is_enabled_on_item: true 
   },
   {
      tagid:2,
      phrase: "yellow",
      is_enabled_on_item: false 
   }
]
```

I tried collect

```
t.collect { |tmp| tmp.is_enabled_on_item=true if current_tag_ids.include?(tmp.tagid) }
```

but itreturns `[true, false]`. How would I achieve what I want?

#### edit #1

I'd want it to return an array of tags.

Something like this would work but the intermediary `arr` seems unnecessary:

```
arr=[]
t.each do |tmp| 
  tmp.is_enabled_on_item=current_tag_ids.include?(tmp.tagid)
  arr << tmp
end  
arr
```

Answer (score 2):

```
t.map do |tmp|
  tmp.attributes.merge(is_enabled_on_item: current_tag_ids.include?(tmp.tagid))
end
```

Comment: hmm... so it looks like that will return an array of  hashes rather than an array of tags

Comment: It's going to return what you requested.. an array of hashes

Answer (score 1):

Your take on collect is almost right, try this:

```
t.collect { |tmp| tmp.is_enabled_on_item=current_tag_ids.include?(tmp.tagid); tmp }
```

Note that assignment returns assigned value, while you have to return tags in block in order to collect tags.

It would be nice to move one step forward and use more canonical method and argument names:

```
tags.map { |tag| tag.is_enabled_on_item=current_tag_ids.include?(tag.tagid); tag }
```